# ActiveRecord condition syntax question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a better way of writing this?  Is it possible to do cleanly in one line?

```
conditions = ["category = ?", params[:category]] if params[:category]
@events = CalendarEvent.all( :conditions => conditions )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really too much to consolidate but you don't have a lot going on so shouldn't matter.

```
def action
    options = {:conditions => ['category=?', params[:category]]} if params[:category]
    @events = CalendarEvent.find(:all, options)
end
```

Comment: I like the hash options.  This will allow me to do the same thing for the other options. thx

Answer (score 0):

```
@events = CalendarEvent.all(
   :conditions => (params[:category] ? ["category = ?", params[:category]] : nil))
```